# How to flatten nested lists in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD structure like:

```
rdd = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5]], [[6]], [[7],[8],[9],[10]]]
```

and I want it to become:

```
rdd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How do I write a map or reduce function to make it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can for example `flatMap` and use list comprehensions:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda xs: [x[0] for x in xs])
```

or to make it a little bit more general:

```
from itertools import chain

rdd.flatMap(lambda xs: chain(*xs)).collect()
```

Comment: thank you so much, i am so new.sorry about the stupid question. you are giving me the right answer!!

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, just did the first item in my own code! You just return an list to flatMap which flattens the many arrays into one rdd of the contents of the lists.