# List of list of Spark Row to Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have list of list of Spark row as follows.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
my_list =[[Row(id=1, col_a=1, col_b=2, col_c=3), 
           Row(id=2, col_a=3, col_b=4, col_c=4)], 
          [Row(id=3, col_a=4, col_b=3, col_c=5)], 
          [Row(id=4, col_a=8, col_b=6, col_c=3), 
           Row(id=5, col_a=1, col_b=4, col_c=4)]]
```

I want to create Spark Dataframe where `id, col_a, col_b, col_c` are my columns. I tried to use `flatMap` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711149/how-to-flatten-nested-lists-in-pyspark) but didn't properly work for me. It would be great if someone know how to do it.

Comment: the linked question applies, you just need `[x for x in xs]` instead of `[x[0] for x in xs]`

Comment: Ahh, I see! `sc.parallelize(my_list).flatMap(lambda xs: [x for x in xs]).take(3)` works, thanks @maxymoo!